# Can't See Namespace in other project

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, csproj, sln-file

I have an asp.net web application project and a regular c# csproj project. My web application project doesn't see the namespace that's in my csproj project after I imported it in and added a reference to it. I have Visual Studio Enterprise 2017. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is regular c# csproj project is class library project?

Comment: How do I find out?

Comment: Which option you have selected while creating the project

Comment: I didn't create it. Someone else did.

Comment: in Visual Studio you can open project details and check which target framework selected. are they same in both? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview?view=vs-2019

Comment: It's a class library with .net standard 2.0

Comment: Your questions seems to be not clearly. What is the relationship between web app and c# project? what are you ready to do about the two app?

Comment: The c# project has all of the engineering code that's needed for the web app.

Comment: Now, I know your meaning. You want to call a class library with .net standard 2.0 in asp.net web app. You can find the dll in the path "TestDll\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\TestDll.dll". Then, you need to add the dll in the asp.net app.